# Tensorflow CNN training stops for no reason

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have this Python code for training a CNN using Tensorflow.
It was working perfectly until I decided to use *MirroredStrategy* to improve the performance. Then it was necessary to make some changes:

1. I had to stop using `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn()` since MirroredStrategy it requires a input function that returns a Dataset.
2. I basically copied the `train_input_fn` from [Datasets for Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets_for_estimators) to use as my input function

Now it seems to work without any problem but it is not training anything at all and after a few seconds it stops running without any error.

Few more details:

1. I'm monitoring my CPU and GPU usage during the training, and when I run the code the GPU frequency raises until the program stops.
2. I already tried to change the batch size, but no changes.
3. My GPU is a GTX 1070 the driver was updated as well and I'm using `tensorflow-gpu` version 1.12.0 in my environment

### Kernel output:

```
In [1]: runfile('D:/MS/CNN.py', wdir='D:/MS')
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing RunConfig with distribution strategies.
INFO:tensorflow:Not using Distribute Coordinator.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': 'models3', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': <tensorflow.contrib.distribute.python.mirrored_strategy.MirroredStrategy object at 0x0000026729AC1320>, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x0000026729AC14A8>, '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_distribute_coordinator_mode': None}
INFO:tensorflow:Device is available but not used by distribute strategy: /device:CPU:0
INFO:tensorflow:Configured nccl all-reduce.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:batch_all_reduce invoked for batches size = 16 with algorithm = nccl, num_packs = 1, agg_small_grads_max_bytes = 0 and agg_small_grads_max_group = 10

In [1]:
```

### Training code:

```
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
    # Shuffle, repeat, and batch the examples.
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat(count=100).batch(batch_size)
    # Return the dataset.
    return dataset

gpu_distribution = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(train_distribute=gpu_distribution)
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn= cria_rede, config=run_config, model_dir='models3')
classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(x_data, y_data, 2), steps= 3000)
#x_data and y_data are bidimensional numpy.ndarrays
```

Comment: What network architecture are you using?

Comment: @Sharky I have 2 convolution layers, 2 pooling layers (convolution, pooling, convolution, pooling) that feeds a Deep NN with 3072 inputs, 5 hidden layers with 1024 nodes each and it outputs 10 nodes. `3072 -> 1024 -> 1024 -> 1024 -> 1024 -> 1024 -> 10` I didn't put the code for the CNN because it was working before, so I thought that it might not be a problem

Comment: Try adding `session_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)` right before MirroredStrategy

Comment: @Sharky Im kind of new with Python and Tensorflow so forgive me if i'm wrong, but this config is for a Session. right? Because I'm not using a session in this code. I understand that the Estimator.train "makes its own session internally". So how do I apply that config?

Comment: You are using session anyway, but Estimator takes care about this for you. but you can get limited access to session object.

Comment: @Sharky well, something definitely happened it's not stopping the run but it's killing the kernel. I'll make some tests

Comment: @Sharky Sadly still the same. Kernel is working but nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried exact same code without MirriredStrategy?